# A ImportError when I install pycaffe without MKL

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I'm doing a project, using IntelCaffe.
but when I run my python code :

```
import sys 
CAFFE_ROOT = '/path/to/caffe/'
sys.path.insert(0, CAFFE_ROOT + 'python')
import caffe
caffe.set_mode_cpu()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "caffemodel.py", line 6, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "../../caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "../../caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 49, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: libmkldnn.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I want to know how to solve it .
hope somebody help me .
Thank you!

Comment: do you have `mkl` installed on your machine? do you know where `libmkldnn.so` is located? does your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to where `libmkldnn.so` is located?

Comment: Thank youI first! didn't install  mkl . but I read the documents it said I can run it without mkl. Is not I did not install this, there is no libmkldnn.so？

Comment: if you did not install mkl you will not have its libraries. Choose another blas in Makefile.config and make sure you installed it.

Comment: I got it .Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the error message, Caffe does not find "libmkldnn.so" in system lib.
So what you need is to install [Intel-mkl-dnn](https://github.com/intel/mkl-dnn).
You have two choice to solve it.

1. You can compile and install it by yourself.
2. Or just use binary packages in conda cloud, if you use conda.

> conda install -c intel mkl-dnn